# How to use flower to monitor more than 1 worker

Tags: docker, celery, flower

Currently, I create a Celery worker + Flower monitoring solution based on

https://github.com/itsrifat/flask-celery-docker-scale

Celery worker and Flower monitoring both run in a same directory `flask-celery`

The reason is that, so that Flower has access to Celery worker code module, and the following command with `-A` flag would work

```yaml
entrypoint: flower
command: -A tasks --port=5555 --broker=redis://redis:6379/0
```

This is what their [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/itsrifat/flask-celery-docker-scale/blob/2467f2d52a81ead48e4f8781ebc2cab57c050e17/docker-compose.yml) looks like

```yaml
worker:
  build:
    context: ./flask-celery
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  depends_on:
    - redis
monitor:
  build:
    context: ./flask-celery
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "5555:5555"
  entrypoint: flower
  command:  -A tasks --port=5555 --broker=redis://redis:6379/0
  depends_on:
    - redis
```

Now, I would like to create another new worker `task2.py` code, which will sit inside new directory called `flask-celery2`.

So, how should I modify the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` so that flower will be capable of monitoring both `tasks` and `tasks2`?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to get this new worker running in a separate container(best practice) and configure in the dockerfile, then flower can automatically monitor this task as long as it is being pushed into the same message broker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use below steps. You have to to your project folder.

```
pip install flower
flower -A proj --port=5555
```

Then you can see in and check in your celery task in browser like http://yourIP:5555